# rabbitmqctl stop_app just hangs

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using windows and am Im trying to stop the rabbitmq app with the command rabbitmqctl stop_app but it just hangs at the command prompt.

I also tried rabbitmqctl stop_app and same thing happens , it just hangs at the command line

I installed it on 3 other servers and ran the same command before joining the servers to a cluster with no issues so not sure why one of the servers is just hanging at the command prompt

Also when i try to start i get the following error : Stop??
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.9\sbin>rabbitmqctl start_app
Starting node 'rabbit@server1' ...
Error: stop

Comment: I actually got the same issue...

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run it with --timeout parameter.
This is not a solution but at least will not wait for infinitely.

As a solution, you can clean(rm -rf) the mnesia folder which is default in /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/

Then re-run the rabbitmq and it will work but don't forget that it will remove all the data!

If you are running a cluster and had this issue with some of the nodes in the cluster then you can do this:

- first: clean the mnesia folder at the nodes which are not working and not connecting to the cluster. (After doing this, reboot is a good idea)

> ```
> rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/*
> ```

- second: remove the node from the cluster (run this command in the node which is running)

> ```
> rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@not-running-node-name
> ```

- later run these in the node which is not running

> ```
> rabbitmqctl stop_app
> rabbitmqctl reset
> rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@running-node-name
> rabbitmqctl start_app
> ```